# How to do i create a unique page for each row in database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say, I enter a row in MySQL database with this form:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="title" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Now, I want to make a page URL like this: `example.com/title`
And when someone open it, the database show that particular row.

Comment: be clear with your question.

Comment: This is just an example. My page will include a lot of data. Like Title, description, videos, image. 

What part you did not understand?

Comment: I just want to make something like CMS. Add something > A page for it automatically gets generated

Comment: Tell here what you have tried, what was the result or error and what exactly result you want

Comment: means example.com/id . fetch data from db based on id

Comment: Use `$_GET` to get the value of the url, like this : `example.com/title?id=1`. Then use the value to retrieve the data from the database based from the `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this to generate "different" page using one file only(`example.com/title.php`)

Loop through your database to get all data while creating a `<a>` for each of them:

```
foreach ($retrieveResult as $result) {
    echo '<a href="example.com/title.php?name='.$result['title'].'">'.$result['title'].'</a>';
}
```

This will generate something like this:

```
<a href="example.com/title.php?name=titleA">titleA</a>
<a href="example.com/title.php?name=titleB">titleB</a>
<a href="example.com/title.php?name=titleC">titleC</a>
<a href="example.com/title.php?name=titleD">titleD</a>
```

To get the value of `name` in the url, use `$_GET` in `title.php`

```
$title = "";
if(isset($_GET['name')){
    $title = $_GET['name'];
}
```

Now put `$title` in a `SELECT` query to retrieve all data that has the title of `$title`, then display it in `title.php`. With this you will have a dynamic page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what actually you want to try but it may be helpful to you

**Follow Steps**

**Step 1:**
If you are familiar with `. htaccess` then it's good, else create a file in your project root folder called `.htaccess` where `htaccess` is it's extension not a name:

Then put this into the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^home/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$    home.php?title=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

**Step 2:** Create file `home.php` in the root folder where `.htaccess` file exist. Now try using global variable `$_GET` to get the *title* from the url and then use it to fetch data from database as:

```
$title = $_GET['title'] // use $title to fetch data from database matching with it
```

**Now** by going through the url as `home/title` you will be able to show data from database about that title:

**Note:** `.htaccess` file is an APACHE server configuration file.